# Problemas en código INSERT INTO en MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un sitio en go daddy pero el código que tengo no me permite subir la tabla, por favor si alguien puede tener una solución se lo agradezco mucho, a continuación dejo el código que actualmente manejo:

```
if(isset($_POST['new'])){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $categoria = $_POST['categoria']; //categoria
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $fechacreacion = date('d-m-Y');

    if (empty($nombre)) {
        echo '<script> window.location="?p=administradores-new&id='.$id.'&error=1"; </script>';
        return;
    }if (empty($categoria)) {
        echo '<script> window.location="?p=administradores-new&id='.$id.'&error=1"; </script>';
        return;
    }
    if (empty($username)) {
        echo '<script> window.location="?p=administradores-new&id='.$id.'&error=1"; </script>';
        return;
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        echo '<script> window.location="?p=administradores-new&id='.$id.'&error=1"; </script>';
        return;
    }

    $nuevo_usuario=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre FROM administracion WHERE nombre='$nombre'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($nuevo_usuario)>0){
        echo '<script> window.location="?p=administradores-new&id='.$id.'&error=2"; </script>';
        return;
    }

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO administracion (id, status, nombre, categoria, username, password, fechacreacion) VALUES ('', 1, '$nombre', '$categoria', '$username', '$password', '$fechacreacion')";
    $resultado = $conexion -> query($consulta)|| die("Ha ocurrido un error al guardar los datos");
    if($resultado)
    {
    echo "Enhorabuena, la acción ha sido llevada a cabo con éxito";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Ha ocurrido un error";
    }

}
```

Comment: Dices que no te deja subir la tabla, podrias compartir el error que estas teniendo siendo mas específico con el mismo. Saludos

Comment: Sigue el consejo de Rostan, te invito a leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tener oportunidad de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Revisa estas dos líneas de tu código: `$consulta = "INSERT INTO administracion (id, status, nombre, categoria, username, password, fechacreacion) VALUES ('', 1, '$nombre', '$categoria', '$username', '$password', '$fechacreacion')";
    $resultado = $conexion -> query($consulta)|| die("Ha ocurrido un error al guardar los datos");` Si `id`  es `auto_increment` sería mejor omitirla del INSERT o pasarle `NULL` en vez de un dato en blanco.  Luego, el `|| die ...`  es extraño, sobra ya que luego preguntas por `$resultado`  en el `if` que sigue. Recomendaría usar consultas preparadas en tu caso.

Comment: si, el ID  "es auto_increment", hice lo que mencionas y me sale el error "Ha ocurrido un error", es extraño pues en otras casas de hospedaje si funciona